# Downgrade migration version in aqueduct

Tags: dart, aqueduct

Is there any way to downgrade migration version in aqueduct. Problem is if I delete migration file which is no longer needed then by running

```
aqueduct db generate
```

it will create migration version with number of deleted version so when running

```
aqueduct db upgrade..
```

then the database are not upgraded due to low version number in migration file so I have to manually change version number to be able to upgrade the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't deployed your database on a production server, then I recommend just dropping the database, recreating it, and starting over with a fresh single migration file.

If you have deployed the database to a live server, then I wouldn't remove any migration files. Just make sure the result of all the migrations is the schema that you need. (If there is a way to decrease the database version number, I'm not sure what it is.)

On another note, don't run

```
aqueduct db generate
```

on your live server. Instead, do it on your dev machine and then use the generated migration file to update the database on the production server. I discovered this the hard way when my dev machine server and production server database versions got out of sync (because I deleted a migration file "that I didn't need".)